# How is a guild mark removed?

Tags: fairy-tail

> After failing to win, Yukino faces the anger of Sabertooth's Guild Master, Jiemma. Displeased by the failure of Team Sabertooth on the second day, Jiemma throws grapes at Yukino's head and forces her to strip, telling her to erase her guild mark,

How exactly does a person remove a guild mark? Is there a special magic for this?

Comment: I don't think they showed this in the anime. Maybe not in the Mangas ever.

Comment: Wasn't it a fake tattoo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We really don't know how the guild mark is removed, but Yukino do it with her own magic.
Sabertooth's Guild Master order her to remove it by her own magic and she do it.

We know that guild marks are given by stamping someone with the rubber seal like thingy. **When Lucy entered the guild, Mira used this device on Lucy to give her the mark**.

> In the battle Lucy vs. Flare, Flare tried to burn the guild mark. {So I think any magic can remove it}.
>  Future Lucy didn't had a guild mark. {Maybe because the guild was destroyed and the guild mark also vanished or someone removed it from her}

This answer is only based on the anime :)

Comment: Future Lucy didn't have her mark any more, because her right arm, the place that the mark was located on, was missing. She had lost her arm during her fights with the dragons.

Answer (score 2):

Menaka gave a good answer but I want to add on:

1. No special magic is needed to remove a guild mark. Mainly because the mark and the guild are most likely connected. We can see this from how Future Lucy teared up after seeing the guild mark on Present Lucy's hand (as mentioned in menaka's answer).
2. Flare actually wanted to use her magic to engrave Raven Tail's mark on her

   [image: Flare's hair burning in the shape of Raven Tail's mark]
3. The mark can only be removed by the person themselves, I would assume. Or else, anyone with magic could easily remove another's guild mark which to some are their pride and joy like Lucy is with Fairy Tail's mark. This can also be seen from how Yukino has to remove the Mark herself in front of her guild at the time.

Comment: doesnt your second point contradict your 3th point ?

Comment: @Dimitrimx nope it does not what i was trying to point out on my second point was that flare wanted to give lucy a scar somewhere of raven tail's guild mark. She did not intend to remove Fairy Tail's mark. She wanted to humiliate Lucy more by making her bear the mark of the enemy guild.

Comment: @xwillflame, I think that somebody else can remove it, because Yukino said, "He made me erase my own Guild mark!" That implies that Jiemma (Sabertooth's Guild master) could have erased it himself or told somebody else to erase it. Also, Natsu was mad at Jiemma for making Yukino erase her own Guild mark.

Answer (score 0):

The guild mark will not really disappear unless the person is banished from the guild.

However, it's true about future Lucy not having one because Fairy Tail didn't exist, like when Wendy found out about her guild Cait Shelter didn't really exist, her guild mark disappeared.

On the other hand, Laxus was banished from the guild but still had his guild mark when he was allowed back, so it doesn't make sense.

In the end, I say it's really only something the master can do.

Answer (score 0):

A person's mark is something that symbolises their part in a team or guild. This mark can't be wiped off easily because it's like a permanent marker stamp. We know this because we can see times when Lucy showers and her mark is still clearly visible.

However, a mark **can** be removed as shown when Wendy's mark was removed from Cait Shelter because the guild was not real or exist but also, the guild then disconnected. Powerful dark magic also is strong enough to do this. If the guild is no longer existing or 'standing', then the mark disappears as the seal is broken as the magic from the stamp is no longer valid. But nobody really knows how to remove a mark.

Answer (score 0):

No one's mentioned this, so I thought I would. When Fairy Tail disbanded after the Tartorous Ordeal, we can still clearly see that Lucy has her guild mark. Gray, Natsu, and Erza are also seen having the Fairy Tail Guild Mark in X792. If the Master had the power to remove guild marks, then I assume that Makarov would've taken away everyone's guild marks to make sure that they didn't have their heart still set upon Fairy Tail.
Because of this, then it's safe to say that it's not the Master who removes guild marks but the person. It seems like removing a guild mark is often traumatizing, based upon Yukino's experience with removing the mark. Of course, she was banished from the guild and in the story with Laxus and the Thunder Legion, we don't see the four showing much remorse about changing their guild marks.
Because of this, I'd go to say that you need to have the magic tool that places guild marks in order for the magic to work. Keeping this in mind, we can assume that a second party would remove the guild mark. I don't know if this is true or not seeing as Minerva also removed and changed her guild mark. So we don't really know a lot about it except that the guild marks can be removed and changed. It might have something to do with how a person identifies themselves? We just don't know a lot. But I just thought to point that out.